# Using a TwoWay binding to an ItemsSource with an IValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ivalueconverter, itemssource

In my ViewModel I have a model class `Foo` which contains a property `Bar`

```
class Foo
{
    byte Bar { get; set; }
}
```

What I want is to show that property in my View as a list of checkboxes representing the bits of this value. I managed to do this by the use of an `ItemsControl` and and a binding converter.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bar, Converter={StaticResource ValueToLed}, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource LedCheckBox}" 
                                    IsChecked="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    ToolTip="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

My Converter uses `BitArray` to get an array of `bool` out of this value. I also wrap each `bool` value inside a wrapper class to provide more properties for that value like index and name (for toolip). You can say I build a ViewModel for such a CheckBox inside my `IValueConverter`.
This works well but in other direction not. When I change one of those bits I want my `ConvertBack` to store the updated value in my ViewModel/Model but my `ConvertBack` is never called. I have read some stuff related to this topic and my conclusion so far is, that is is not possible to do so because the `ConvertBack` would be only called when the `ItemsSource` itself changes and not an item inside it. So is this really true?

The only(?) alternative to this approach would be to do the conversion in my ViewModel and not in an `IValueConverter`, right?

Comment: sorry, i meant `byte` which is actually an unsigned byte.

Answer (score 2):

The C# language (and also a C# developer) should be unaware (i.e. allergic) to the internal bit representation. Whereas you need any boolean variable, just use it.

If your program deal with some low-level interfaces (e.g. bit mask in a I/O stream ), just pack/unpack the actual byte-array at the closest possible level.

That said, WPF and bits are *very allergic* themselves, and a checkbox bound to a single bit requires an uselessly yet messy code. I won't suggest to follow this way.

Just expose your un/check variable in your MVVM pattern, as a part of each item being templated in the list. The checkbox binding would be straightforward and your code clean.

EDIT: I understand right now what's your problem.

Did you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged pattern in the bools' wrapper, specifically for the "Value" property?

EDIT2: This is working fine for me.

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Bar}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox  
                    IsChecked="{Binding Value,Mode=TwoWay}"
                    ToolTip="{Binding Name}"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Here is the ViewModel:

```
class MyCollection
{
    public IEnumerable<MyWrapper> Bar { get; set; }
}

class MyWrapper : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region PROP Value

    private bool _value;

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return this._value; }
        set
        {
            if (this._value != value)
            {
                this._value = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
                Console.WriteLine("changed="+ this._value);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion


    #region EVT PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(
                this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

When a checkbox is clicked, the related property is modified. The Console.Writeline prove it.

EDIT3: Correct the code as follows:

```
class MyCollection : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region PROP Bar

    private byte _bar;

    public byte Bar
    {
        get { return this._bar; }
        set
        {
            if (this._bar != value)
            {
                this._bar = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Bar");
                Console.WriteLine("bar="+ this._bar);
                this.UpdateItems();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion


    public void UpdateItems()
    {
        //rebuild the children collection
        var collection = new List<MyWrapper>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            var item = new MyWrapper();
            item.Value = ((this._bar >> i) & 1) != 0;
            collection.Add(item);
        }
        this.Items = collection;
    }


    #region PROP Items

    private IEnumerable<MyWrapper> _items;

    public IEnumerable<MyWrapper> Items
    {
        get { return this._items; }
        set
        {
            if (this._items != value)
            {
                this._items = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Items");

                if (this._items != null)
                {
                    foreach (var child in this._items)
                    {
                        child.PropertyChanged += child_PropertyChanged;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    void child_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //rebuild the scalar value
        int value = 0;
        foreach (var item in this._items)
        {
            value = value >> 1;
            if (item.Value) value |= 0x80;
        }
        this.Bar = (byte)value;
    }


    #region EVT PropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = this.PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(
                this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Comment: For me bit manipulations (i write a electro technical application) and WPF are not exclusive but as you also relaized later that's not the point here. Yes my bool wrapper fires a PropertyChanged event when bool value changes but this does not fire the ConvertBack since the collection itself (which is also obervable) does not change - like helb also mention in his post.

Comment: I'm too develop software for exchanging data with embedded devices, but the framework and the C# tend you to abstract the internal representation. However, the observability of the collection isn't important, unless you have to modify the number of bits. Have a look here: http://cetdevelop.codeplex.com/

Comment: The converter is unnecessary. My suspect is about your LedCheckBox style: could you show us?

Comment: My point is not beeing able to get a PropertyChanged event when a checkbox is toggled. The difference from your example to my scenario is that `Bar` is not a collection of any kind but an ubyte. Therefore I need a converter, to make a collection out of this single value, which works fine, but the other way round, to make a single value out of that collection when one item inside that collection changes, does not work. I will change my model to provide a collection of `bool`instead of a single `ubyte` value. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Again, what is a "ubyte"??? There's the "byte" and the "sbyte": no "ubyte" at all!

Comment: sorry, i meant `byte` which is actually an unsigned byte

Comment: I suspected that: just wanted a confirm. Anyway, I'd suggest to change the ViewModel: start from the above example, checked and rock solid! ...and...I know it very well, when you deal with small devices, where just one byte is relevant, it sounds strange "wasting" bytes. BTW, the  huge redundancy of the C# language yields you huge benefits as well! Good luck...

Comment: Ay, i cannot change the data type of `Bar` from scalar to collection (array, enum, whatever) because it comes from database which has no array type and I use entity framework. Hm it's complicated to explain ...

Comment: OK. I've corrected the MyCollection class and now it works as you expect. Remember to call the UpdateItems method at least once on init, because the items aren't refreshed otherwise. OH! The ItemsSource should bind to Items, now.

Comment: your last draft would work if I would expose my scalar in ViewModel and do the convertion / backconvertion there. Unfortunatly I don't have it there, that's why I use IValueConverter. But with that I have no access to that generated collection, or do I? In my VM I have a collection of objects Foo which are displayed by an ItemsControl in View. In ItemTemplate I bind to Property Bar of Item Foo. Sorry that I did not give as much detail about my situation in the first place ...

Comment: ok now I think I have a solution. I can't change the data type in model but I can extend my model class to have the converter/backconverter there.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a value converter to convert a single ubyte value to checked/unchecked for the Checkbox since the ConvertBack method of the Converter is not called for the collection if a value for an item in the collection changes.

Your XAML should look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Bar">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource LedCheckBox}" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Value, 
                                          Mode=TwoWay,
                                          Converter={StaticResource ValueToLedConverter},
                                          UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      ToolTip="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I will change my model to a collection of bool and bind that to my checkboxes. This way I won't need a converter at all. Thank you.